# Javascript, build object path from list

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build an object path based upon a list that I am being passed. I have set up an example of what I mean here :

https://jsfiddle.net/alexjm/kypwht31/6/

```
var state = { irc : { main : "test"}};

var key = ["irc", "main"];


createStateFromKey = function (key) {
    var stateForBuild = "state";
    _.each(key, function(n, key) {
    stateForBuild += "." + n;
  });

  return stateForBuild;
};


console.log(createStateFromKey(key));
```

this sends me back the string of 'state.irc.main' which is what I want, but I want it to be an evaluation of the actual object - "test". I am being passed this list that can have any number of items, and need to search inside that state  using the key list i am being provided with. I am using it in a function like so :

```
function mapStateToProps(key, state) {

return {
    test: state.???.loadingJSON
 };
}
```

so it needs to evaluate on that state, something like this:

```
return {
    test: state[key[0]].[key[1]].loadingJSON
 };
```

I am trying to run it into a for each because the length of that list is dynamic. I am not entirely sure I am approaching this correctly because that function is returning a string that i am not sure is working. Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I was about to close it as a duplicate of that question too, when Felix did. That question and its answers have your answer, you just have the advantage that you don't have to parse the string first.

Comment: awesome, thanks guys!